# xslt: working with attribute values to retrieve another "same parent" element's attribute

Tags: xml, xslt, attributes, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I have the following xml, where there can be multiple Person and Location elements:

```
<ProtectionOrderResponse>
  <Person id="PRTPER1">
    <!--child elements-->
  </Person>
  <Location id="PRTADR1"> 
    <!--child elements-->
  </Location>
  <PersonLocationAssociation>
        <PersonReference ref="PRTPER1"/>
        <LocationReference ref="PRTADR1"/>
  </PersonLocationAssociation>
</ProtectionOrderResponse>
```

I need an xslt that iterates through each Person element to retrieve its id attribute and match it with the ref attribute of the PersonLocationAssociation/PersonReference. From there, I would like to obtain the attribute value "PRTADR1" and put it into a variable using xslt given the Person attribute value "PRTPER1".
The following is the simplified version of the xslt that I'm working on:

```
<xsl:template match="//ProtectionOrderResponse">
  <!--Although I'm iterating through all the Person elements, I only want to select particular Person elements that match a specific criteria, not sure how to do this yet so I will put the logic in the template section-->
  <xsl:for-each select="//Person">
     <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Person">
<!--Logic to only process the Person element that matches a particular criteria and get the LocationReference for that Person-->
<xsl:variable name="PerID" select="Person/@id"/>
  <!-- need to obtain the ref attribute value of PersonLocationAssociation/LocationReference for the PersonLocationAssociation/PersonReference[@ref=$PerID]-->
</xsl:template>
```

What I need is to obtain the ref attribute value of PersonLocationAssociation/LocationReference for the PersonLocationAssociation/PersonReference[@ref=$PerID]. How would I do this? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use keys:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:key name="ref-per" match="ProtectionOrderResponse/Person" use="@id"/>

    <xsl:key name="ref-loc" match="PersonLocationAssociation/LocationReference" use="../PersonReference/@ref"/>

    <xsl:template match="ProtectionOrderResponse">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="key('ref-per', 'PRTPER1')"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Person">
        <xsl:variable name="ref" select="key('ref-loc', @id)/@ref"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$ref"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Do you know if there is a way to do a template match on a particular Person based on the id? In other words, using the following: <xsl:apply-templates select="Person[@s:id=$PerID]"> and in the template match on a person with a particular @id?

Comment: I tried to do something like this:                                                    <xsl:variable name="LocID" select="//Person[@id=$PersonID]/key('ref', @id)/@ref"/>                                                                                                                but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: If you have a new question ask a new one, I don't see any `@s:id` attributes at all and as you already match on a `Person` element I don't understand why you want to apply-templates again.

Comment: I apologize, it's @id, I removed the namespace prefixes to simplify the question. It's a new question, but since it's related, I didn't want to write up a whole new thread. thanks!

Comment: I don't want to retrieve all the LocationReference for all the Person elements. I have more logic to select a particular Person and using the Person's @id, I get the LocationReference. Thanks for taking the time to answer.

Comment: I think my suggestion shows how to find the referenced `LocationReference` element based on the `id` attribute of a `Person` elements in the context of a `match="Person"` template. If you don't want to process all `Person` elements then I don't understand why you posted code `<xsl:for-each select="//Person"><xsl:apply-templates select="."/> </xsl:for-each>` processing all `Person` elements. My variant with `<xsl:template match="ProtectionOrderResponse"><xsl:apply-templates select="Person"/></xsl:template>` is just an attempt at a simplification, you can ignore it.

Comment: I posted xsl:for-each select="//Person" because I didn't know how to do a template match on a particular person (I tried using <xsl:apply-templates select="Person[@s:id=$PerID]"> ), but it didn't work, so within the template, I added additional logic to interrogate the Person element and only retrieve the LocationReference of the Person that fits a particular criteria. I hope this makes sense. thanks!

Comment: I have edited the answer to show the use of a further key to select a `Person` by `id` attribute value. I am still not sure what you want to achieve, you might want to edit the question and show minimal but complete samples of input and corresponding output you want to create with XSLT.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143126/discussion-between-ptn77-and-martin-honnen).